# Best way to handle dynamic templates in Meteor 1.3?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, dynamic

What is the best practice for importing dynamic templates in Blaze with new 1.3 module feature? Should we import every possible subtemplate into the one where we call them dynamically? What if I have 100 different routes that call a dynamic subtemplate in my main layout template?

For example, do I have to code like this?

```js
import 'template1.js';
import 'template2.js';
import 'template3.js';
import 'template4.js';
//can be more.....

let navItems = ['template1', 'template2', 'template3', 'template4', ....];
```

```html
<ul>
  {{#each navItems}}
    <li>
      {{> UI.dynamic template=this}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```